# Scheduling App for Rails Beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

I'm starting to work my way through the fantastic Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl (https://www.railstutorial.org/), and I wanted to bounce a project idea off you all to get a sense for how realistic it is for a beginner. I'd like to make a scheduling/staffing app for my company. I'm envisioning something where the rows correspond to employees, and the columns correspond to days - sort of like the "Week View" in a calendar app, but the time slots would be replaced with employee names. Eventually this could grow into something more sophisticated where you can filter and sort by various employee responsibilities.

So my question is: does this seem like a realistic project for a Rails beginner? I'm not asking for specific suggestions here. I'm just hoping to get some general guidance on whether or not this is biting off too much to chew, so to speak. I have no familiarity with Ruby or Rails, and I haven't touched HTML since I was 10 years old and making sites on Angelfire and Geocities, but I do consider myself fluent in a number of other scripting languages. Open-ended replies are encouraged. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those questions that really does not have an answer.

Yes, generally, beginners should build projects that familiarize them with the ecosystem of the framework and it's constructs but it also depends on how good you are at learning things.

The project that you have described may be hard for a Rails beginner to do but at the same time, it can be very easy because a lot of skills come into account.

My approach is mostly to first read the documentation of the framework I am about to use thoroughly so that I do not re-invent the wheel(do something a certain way when the framework has built in functionality to do that thing very easily). The rest I think is just dependent on how good your programming skills are.

Welcome to the Rails world!